# Calling records for form on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am completely stuck on how to do this and hopefully, someone can point me in the correct direction.  I have a rails app that has crewmembers, which are part of departments and each has the positions.  I am looking to make a master list feature where a page is created with all the crewmembers' names and their respective position, grouped by department.  In the creation phase I would like the user to be able to remove names from the list that they don't want to print. However, I don't want the actual crewmembers to be deleted.  Any insight would be great.

Comment: what is your problem? Group crewmembers by department, or how to print expected ones? Better if you update your current code, and which part you stuck on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field named `:visible`, by running `rails generate migration add_visible_to_crewmembers visible:boolean`.

Add a default value (of `true`, as you want the crewmembers to be normally visible) to your migration:

```ruby
def up
  change_column :visible, :boolean, default: true
end

def down
  change_column :visible, :boolean, default: nil
end
```

Persist these changes to your database, by running `rake db:migrate`.

After that, you can create a scope in your Crewmember model (`apps/models/crewmember.rb`) to return only the visible crewmembers, like this:

```ruby
class Crewmember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  [...]
  scope :visible, where(visible: true)
end
```

In your controller, use this scope instead of the default one (or using `#all`, for instance):

```ruby
def index
  # Before:
  # @crewmembers = Crewmember.all
  # @crewmembers.size => 10
  @crewmembers = Crewmember.visible
  # @crewmembers.size => 5
end
```

Comment: If I have a different part of the app where I need to manage crew members like view edit, etc; can I use Crewmember.visible just for the callsheets controller?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you need to select only the visible crewmembers, you can use Crewmember.visible, be it in a controller, inside another model, class etc.

Comment: How could I go about the functionality of changing the visible state via the new callsheet form?

Comment: You would save the "visible" state the same way you save the crewmember's name, for example. You might have a checkbox in the form, and when you turn it off and save the record, it redirects you to the "master list". In the master list, as you're scoping the query, the crewmember won't be there anymore. If you want to do it all in the same page, "dynamically", you have to combine [Rails with Javascript](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) (by using a remote form, for instance)